# position: absolute to be absolute to the browser/window

Tags: internet-explorer, quirks-mode, css

It's my understanding that `position: absolute` is absolute to the first parent who has a non-static position. If no parent has a specified position, then it will be absolute to the browser/window.

`position: fixed` on the other hand will be absolute to the browser, however it does not work for IE if in quirks mode.

My problem is that I want something to be `top:0; left:0;` but the website is in quirks mode, and I only edit inside my personal div. (it's a user website like myspace). There are many parent divs that have `position: relative`.

How can I get `position: absolute` to act like `position: fixed` without the need of the object being stationary  (it can be stationary if need be)?

Comment: Can you kill that whole outside html using javascript? `<script>document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = "<div>this is my div</div>";</script>`

Comment: @thejh  I tried that and IE complains "Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed"

Comment: Do it in an onload handler. Add a `load` handler to the window.

Comment: Dude, I feel your pain and understand your question and am having the same issue right now.  =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

early versions of IE just dont support position: fixed;

the only thing i know of is a javacript workaround like so:

```
var layerPadding = 5;
function layerScrollFixEx() {
    if (layerGetScrollPosition() != (document.getElementById('layer').offsetTop - layerPadding)) {
        document.getElementById('layer').style.top = layerGetScrollPosition() + layerPadding + "px";
    }
}

function layerGetScrollPosition() {
    if (typeof window.pageYOffset != 'undefined') {
         return window.pageYOffset;
    }
    else if (typeof document.compatMode != 'undefined' && document.compatMode != 'BackCompat') {
         return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
        else if (typeof document.body != 'undefined') {
         return document.body.scrollTop;
    }
}
layerScrollInterval = window.setInterval("layerScrollFixEx()", 1);
```

this is a code excerpt from some code that i did a while back when this was still relevant.

Comment: This seems to only mimic the ability to "fix" in one place by redefining its position. I am looking to to do `top:0;left:0` in reference to the browser window

Comment: thats exactly it, the sample only shows the fix for vertical scrolling... but you can easily adapt it

Comment: you want the element to stay where it is while scrolling dont you? thats what position fixed is. otherwise you would need position absolute, which is perfectly supported...